# Understanding CAtlArray::SetCount

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

I don't quite understand how to call `CAtlArray::SetCount`.

This is the signature:

```
bool SetCount(size_t nNewSize, int nGrowBy = - 1);
```

And here's an explanation of the parameters, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/catlarray-class?view=msvc-170#setcount):

> *nNewSize*
>
> The required size of the array.
>
> *nGrowBy*
>
> A value used to determine how large to make the buffer. A
> value of -1 causes an internally calculated value to be used.

So, let's say you have an array of some current length, and you'd like to add another 7 units to it.  How would you call `SetCount`?  Do you get the current count, add 7, and then pass that number as the first argument?  Or do you just pass 7 as the second argument -- and if so, what's the first argument?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If you want to increase the array size by 7, then `int ct = iArray.GetCount();`, followed by `iArray.SetCount(ct+7, -1);`.  Or `iArray.SetCount(iArray.GetCount()+7, -1);`  PS: I'd definitely discourage you from writing any new ATL code (or any new COM/ActiveX code in general) if you can avoid it: [Is ActiveX Obsolete?](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+ATL+obsolete)

Comment: Well I'm avoiding ActiveX for sure, but I think it's hard to avoid COM, and ATL is by far the best library for doing COM stuff.

Comment: @pau How do you avoid writing COM code? The entire [Windows Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) is based on COM. That includes [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/).

Comment: ActiveX was more or less a marketing name (that indeed is obsolete). But the underlying technology (COM, OLE, etc.) is still used everywhere in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of details on the `nGrowBy` parameter is a hint that Microsoft's guys do not want ordinary programmers to use it. For normal operations you can ignore it and trust the default value of -1 to do the right thing.

So the correct way to add a number of items is what you guessed:

- find the current size if you do not have it at hand
- add the number or units to add
- and pass that value as the first argument of `SetCount` (leaving the default value of -1 for the second argument)

Answer (score 0):

`nGrowBy` sets storage growing strategy.

| nGrowBy | Strategy |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | Use last set strategy. If not set, default strategy is 0. |
| 0 | Set default strategy which grows storage by at least 50%. |
| >0 | Set new strategy which grows storage by at least `nGrowBy` items. |

Every time when `nNewSize` is larger than size calculated by growing strategy, `nNewSize` is used instead of calculated value (this explains *at least* in above table).

In most cases you should use just `-1` (not specify it at all). Providing explicit value for `nGrowBy` makes sense only when you know something special on future array resizing, but even then in most cases it is better to just `SetCount( final_size )`.